# Route selection in RIPv2 and RIPng (equal hop count)

Tags: routing, router, rip, redundant-routes, next-hop

How do RIPv2/RIPng select between equal routes? Randomly?

For example, 2 broadcast domains, 5 routers, all running RIPv2 and RIPng. The `|` pipes represent a switch:

```
 R01  
     | R02
     | R03 | 
     | R04 |    
           | R05
```

How does R01 decide between R02/R03/R03?

Commentary: There are no static routes. Timers are the same on each router. There are only two IPv4 and two IPv6 networks.

Comment: The answer actually depends on the manufacturer of the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco routers can load balance across equal-cost routes, but you don't give a router make/model. The RFC for RIPv2, [RFC 2453, RIP Version 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2453), actually discusses equal-cost routes:

> If the new metric is the same as the old one, it is simplest to do
> nothing further (beyond re-initializing the timeout, as specified
> above); but, there is a heuristic which could be applied.  Normally,
> it is senseless to replace a route if the new route has the same
> metric as the existing route; this would cause the route to bounce
> back and forth, which would generate an intolerable number of
> triggered updates.  However, if the existing route is showing signs of
> timing out, it may be better to switch to an equally-good alternative
> route immediately, rather than waiting for the timeout to happen.
> Therefore, if the new metric is the same as the old one, examine the
> timeout for the existing route.  If it is at least halfway to the
> expiration point, switch to the new route.  This heuristic is
> optional, but highly recommended.